# React-native FlatList not updating

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, updating

I am creating react-native FlatList with 3 stages of colors from not selected item on orange light to double-selected on strong orange. The color stage goes from 0 to 2.

- if I had onPress with setSelectionColors([0,1,2]) then the colors would appear correct after the first time I press one of those items (light orange, moderate orange, strong orange);
- if onPress has setSelectionColors(selectionColors) - as code bellow - then it never updates the color of each item... *so what I am missing here*??

````
const itemsOfList = [
  {
    id: "1",
    title: "First Item",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    title: "Second Item",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    title: "Third Item",
  },
];


const Receita = () => {
  
  const [selectionColors, setSelectionColors] = useState([0,0,0]);
  
  function getColorStyleFromArray(myidx) {
    switch (selectionColors[myidx]) {
      case 0: return styles.colorOrangeLight;
      case 1: return styles.colorOrangeModerate;
      case 2: return styles.colorOrangeHeavy;
      default: return styles.colorOrangeLight;
    }
  }

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            selectionColors[index]= (selectionColors[index]+1)%3;
            setSelectionColors(selectionColors);
            }} style={[styles.item, getColorStyleFromArray(index)]}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={itemsOfList}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        extraData={selectionColors}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};```
````

Comment: Where you defined itemsOfList ?

Comment: `const itemsOfList = [...` is right after the imports on the start of file, I've omitted this part and also the definition of styles in the end of file on the question posted.

Now I tested replacing `selectionColors[index]= (selectionColors[index]+1)%3;` by a map operation like 
`const tempColorsArray = selectionColors.map(mapFuncNextColor);`
 and then `setSelectionColors(tempColorsArray);` and it worked!
But I still would be very glad to understand why the previous code was failing